# Using an Airport Extreme to distribute files to local units without internet?

Tags: network, wifi, airport, internet

I have an old Aiport Extreme 802.11n 5th Gen and while plugged in to a router or ethernet with Internet, it is as we know possible to access any attached storage to a Mac which is connected to the Airport, from other units, such as an iPad.

Now, I'm wondering, whether it's possible to do this without the use of any internet (bar possibly the exception of using your iphone as a personal hotspot?)

This could be any type of local client based server, SMB or WEBDAV or whatnot, as long as my Macs files can be accessed through the Airport unit without being connected to the internet.

Grateful for help!

Answer (score 1):

You can always run a local storage server based on SMB, WebDAV or similar protocol - and access it from other units that are connected network-wise to that storage server.

You do not need internet connectivity, nor do you need an AirPort Extreme.

You can use any (reasonable) kind of network switch to connect multiple Macs together, and you can use any (reasonable) kind of Wireless Access Point or Wireless Router to get iPhones and iPads connected as well. It does not have to be "AirPort" branded.

Comment: That was pretty much the clarification that I was looking for. Thank you!